# Is Redim Preserve threadsafe?

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety

I'm running multiple tasks using Task.Run(). My tasks each need to edit a multi-dimensional array... aka...

```
Dim BigArray(3)() as integer
```

So each thread will need to do a number of Redim Preserve's, but they'll be resizing the second dimension of the array. Each thread will basically be redimming their own part of the array... For example...

```
Thread 1 will: Redim Preserve BigArray(0)(50)
Thread 2 will: Redim PReserve BigArray(1)(50)
Thread 3 will: Redim Preserve BigArray(2)(50)
```

Is it safe? What happens if two threads are redimming at the same time? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redim` will read the current array reference, do some processing and assign a new array reference. This get-set cycle is not thread-safe. It is unsafe for the same reason `x = x + 1` is not thread-safe.

Comment: I assume you mean that the whole multidimensional array is unsafe to redim then, even though each thread is only resizing part of it?

Comment: Use collections, not arrays, if you need the sizes to change. See the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace for thread-safe collection types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx

Comment: Redim does not change the size of a CLR array because the CLR does not allow that. Instead VB arranges for a new array to be created with the desired size. Redim works like this pseudocode: `array = CreateResizedCopy(array, newSize)`. `CreateResizedCopy` is a runtime library function. `array` is a local or field of type `int[]`.